# Change NULL values in Datetime format to empty string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table which contains 'NULL' values which are of type 'Datetime'. Now i have to convert those into empty string but when when i use convert function

```
ISNULL( [Accrued Out of Default] ,'' )
```

here accrued into default is of datetime type, what it does it changes null to '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' instead of empty

Then i try to convert them into varchar and apply same

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),  [Amort Into Default] ),'')
```

Now I am able to convert into empty string but now those datetime are converted to string which I needed in datetime 
So I try to CAST, CONVERT but non of them works.

```
CONVERT(Datetime,'ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),  [Amort Into Default] ),'')',120)
```

This gives error.

Is there any possible solution to this.

```
> **Solution Hi someone answered this to do as.
>      ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),  [Amort Into Default] ,120),'') and it works  I dont know why .
```

**

Comment: In the result set all values of one field have to be the same data type. So you can't output some values as VARCHAR and other as a DATETIME. You should parse it on client side or output all values as a VARCHAR type.

Comment: A `datetime` value is *incapable* of storing a *string*. There is no way to simultaneously have a) that the type of the result expression is of type `datetime`, and b) that a row contains something other than a valid datetime value or NULL.

Answer (score 49):

CASE and CAST should work:

```
CASE WHEN mycol IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), mycol, 121) END
```

Answer (score 14):

using an ISNULL is the best way I found of getting round the NULL in dates :

```
ISNULL(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, YOURDate) = '1900-01-01' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), YOURDate, 103) END, '') AS [YOUR Date]
```

Comment: this worked really good for me. I had some case statements working out the dates I wanted and just kept the 1900-01-01 date in there into a temp table then just applied this line to each applicable line from the select on the temp table. I only did this because I'm working with only 13 columns; anymore than that I would have done something else - it was just cleaner and more readable.

Comment: why invoking CONVERT twice? You need only evaluate IS NULL, like the answer of @Bohemian

Comment: Worked great. Just had to be mindful of the date format.

Comment: would be able to use the same logic in an SSIS expression? if so how would it be formulated

Answer (score 7):

```
declare @date datetime; set @date = null
--declare @date datetime; set @date = '2015-01-01'

select coalesce( convert( varchar(10), @date, 103 ), '')
```

Comment: I did something similar to you, though used ISNULL in lieu of COALESCE

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar, and here's (an edited) version of what I ended up using successfully:

`ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[column name goes here],[date style goes here] ),'')`

Here's why this works: If you select a date which is NULL, it will show return NULL, though it is really stored as 01/01/1900. This is why an ISNULL on the date field, while you're working with any date data type will *not* treat this as a NULL, as it is technically not being stored as a NULL.

However, once you convert it to a new datatype, it will convert it as a NULL, and at that point, you're ISNULL will work as you expect it to work.

I hope this works out for you as well!

~Eli

**Update, nearly one year later:**

I had a similar situation, where I needed the output to be of the date data-type, and my aforementioned solution didn't work (it only works if you need it displayed as a date, not be of the date data type.

If you *need* it to be of the date data-type, there *is* a way around it, and this is to nest a `REPLACE` within an `ISNULL`, the following worked for me:

```
Select 
    ISNULL(
        REPLACE(
            [DATE COLUMN NAME],
            '1900-01-01',
            ''
        ),
    '') AS [MeaningfulAlias]
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
REPLACE(ISNULL(CONVERT(DATE, @date), ''), '1900-01-01', '') AS 'Your Date Field'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow. In the future, consider adding a little more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @mydatetime datetime
set @mydatetime = GETDATE() -- comment out for null value
--set @mydatetime = GETDATE()

select 
case when @mydatetime IS NULL THEN ''
else convert(varchar(20),@mydatetime,120)
end as converted_date
```

In this query, I worked out the result came from current date of the day.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when IsNull(CONVERT(DATE, StartDate),'')='' then 'NA' else Convert(varchar(10),StartDate,121) end from table1
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to you code (and you can indent it with four spaces to create a code block).

Answer (score 1):

```
Select isnull(date_column_name,cast('1900-01-01' as DATE)) from table name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

select 
case when mydatetime IS NULL THEN ''
else convert(varchar(20),@mydatetime,120)
end as converted_date
from sometable

```
-- Testing it out could do --

declare @mydatetime datetime
set @mydatetime = GETDATE() -- comment out for null value
--set @mydatetime = GETDATE()

select 
case when @mydatetime IS NULL THEN ''
else convert(varchar(20),@mydatetime,120)
end as converted_date
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function DECODE

Ex: Decode(MYDATE, NULL, ' ', MYDATE)

If date is NULL then display ' ' (BLANK) else display the date.