# SQL Date Return If Null Then Blank

Tags: sql, date, null

I currently have the following code:

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, BirthDateTime) IS NULL THEN '' END AS DOB,
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, ServiceDateTime) IS NULL THEN '' END AS [Admission Date],
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DischargeDateTime) IS NULL THEN '' END AS [Discharge Date],
```

It returns:

[image]

What is the best way to still convert the date to Date (original field is datetime) and if it is Null then return blank or ' '

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? When you were writing your question and added the SQL tag, a large box was shown to you that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS, because syntax and functionality differ between them. Why did you decide to ignore that suggestion?

Comment: ISNULL (COLUMNNAME,  '') in sql server, and check out coalesce as well for learning purpose .

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  --- I don't understand. SQL Server 2012?

Comment: When you were writing your question and added the SQL tag, a large box was shown to you that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS, because syntax and functionality differ between them. Why did you decide to ignore that suggestion? --- I have been tagging them. I don't know why it doesn't show.

Comment: @cmpmd2: you have to click the tag after typing part of it, or type it in full

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change NULL values in Datetime format to empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930599/change-null-values-in-datetime-format-to-empty-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server:

Since you want to use an empty string instead of `null`, then you are going to be converting to a string. You can use the size of `10` along with style `120` to return iso format (without the time portion) like so:

```
select 
    dob = isnull(convert(varchar(10),BirthDateTime,120),'')
  , [Admission Date] = isnull(convert(varchar(10),ServiceDateTime,120),'')
  , [Discharge Date] = isnull(convert(varchar(10),DischargeDateTime,120),'')
from ...
```

You can find the other style codes for `convert()` here: [docs: cast and convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: I would change just one thing - use `char(10)` instead of `varchar(10)`, since it's a fixed length.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Usually I would, but since `null` is being converted to an empty string, and the conversion would change the empty string into 10 blank spaces... I just don't like a bunch of space characters in my result set instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use coalesce.  A column must always have one type regardless of row, so you have to convert your date type to a text type before you pass it to coalesce:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), BirthDateTime), '') AS DOB,
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL SERVER

go with

```
SELECT ISNULL(DOB,'') AS DOB FROM TABLE
```

Comment: That won't work, both arguments to `isnull` must have the same type